# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js) after upgrade angular 11 to 15

Tags: css, angular, sass, build, module

I have tried to upgrade angular 11 to 15 and now I get the error exposed in the screesnhot below

./src/assets/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected "(".
╷
90 │     $cragcity-toolbar-typography: mat.define-legacy-typography-configmat.define-legacy-typography-config(
│                                                                         ^
╵
assets\cragcity-theme.scss 90:73  @import
assets\styles.scss 1:9            root stylesheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meK8J.png)

styles.scss

```
@import './material-overrides.scss';

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LuloCleanW01-OneBold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-display: swap;
    src: local('LuloCleanW01-OneBold Bold'), url(../assets/fonts/FontsFree-Net-Lulo-Clean-W01-One-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');
}

body { 
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Raleway',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
}

input, textarea, select, button {
    font-family: 'Raleway',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

:focus {
    outline: none;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #757575 !important;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #757575 !important;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #757575 !important;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #757575 !important;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

h1, h2 {
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-word;
}

// common margins paddings etc...
.m-l-0 {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.m-r-0 {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.m-t-0 {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.m-b-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.m-y-0 {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.m-x-0 {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.m-l-5 {
    margin-left: 5px !important;
}

.m-r-5 {
    margin-right: 5px !important;
}

.m-t-5 {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.m-b-5 {
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.m-y-5 {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.m-x-5 {
    margin-left: 5px !important;
    margin-right: 5px !important;
}

.m-l-15 {
    margin-left: 15px !important;
}

.m-r-15 {
    margin-right: 15px !important;
}

.m-t-15 {
    margin-top: 15px !important;
}

.m-b-15 {
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.m-y-15 {
    margin-top: 15px !important;
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.m-x-15 {
    margin-left: 15px !important;
    margin-right: 15px !important;
}

.m-l-30 {
    margin-left: 30px !important;
}

.m-r-30 {
    margin-right: 30px !important;
}

.m-t-30 {
    margin-top: 30px !important;
}

.m-b-30 {
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
}

.m-y-30 {
    margin-top: 30px !important;
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
}

.m-t-50 {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
}

.m-b-50 {
    margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}

.m-y-50 {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
    margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}

.p-l-0 {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.p-r-0 {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.p-t-0 {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}

.p-b-0 {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.p-l-5 {
    padding-left: 5px !important;
}

.p-r-5 {
    padding-right: 5px !important;
}

.p-t-5 {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
}

.p-b-5 {
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.p-y-5 {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.p-x-5 {
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
}

.p-l-10 {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.p-r-10 {
    padding-right: 10px !important;
}

.p-t-10 {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}

.p-b-10 {
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.p-y-10 {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.p-x-10 {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-right: 10px !important;
}

.p-l-15 {
    padding-left: 15px !important;
}

.p-r-15 {
    padding-right: 15px !important;
}

.p-t-15 {
    padding-top: 15px !important;
}

.p-b-15 {
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.p-y-15 {
    padding-top: 15px !important;
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.p-x-15 {
    padding-left: 15px !important;
    padding-right: 15px !important;
}

.p-15 {
    padding: 15px !important;
}

.p-15 {
    padding: 30px !important;
}

.p-l-30 {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}

.p-r-30 {
    padding-right: 30px !important;
}

.b-r-0 {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.b-r-5 {
    border-radius: 5px !important;
}

.txt-center {
    text-align: center !important;
}

.txt-right {
    text-align: right !important;
}

.txt-left {
    text-align: left !important;
}

.h-100pcnt {
    height: 100% !important;
}

.w-100pcnt {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.f-w-300 {
    font-weight: 300 !important;
}

.f-w-400 {
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}

.f-w-600 {
    font-weight: 600 !important;
}

.f-w-700 {
    font-weight: 700 !important;
}

.fnt-xs {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.cragcity-container {
    @include cragcity_container;
}

.cragcity-section {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.cragcity-card {
    border: 1px solid rgba(44, 44, 43, 0.2);
}

/*============= material overrides =============*/

.signup-page {

    .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label, .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy.mat-form-field-can-float .mat-input-server:focus + .mat-form-field-label-wrapper .mat-form-field-label {
        transform: translateY(-1.28125em) scale(1) perspective(100px) translateZ(0.00106px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-1.28119em) scale(1);
        
    }

    .mat-form-field {
        input.mat-input-element {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .mat-form-field-underline {
            height: 0.5px;
        }
    }
}

.register-choose-category.mat-tree-node .mat-checkbox {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.mat-accordion + .mat-error, .mat-checkbox + .mat-error, re-captcha + .mat-error {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

the package.json

```
  "name": "cragcity-website",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "15.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "15.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "15.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "15.1.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "15.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "15.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "15.1.4",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^31.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload": "^31.0.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "3.5.7",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.2",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "14.0.0",
    "ngx-treeview": "10.0.2",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "13.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.1.5",
    "@angular/cli": "15.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.8.1",
    "@types/node": "12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.8.0",
    "karma": "6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.7.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  }
}
```

cragcity-theme.scss

```
@import './cragcity-palette.scss';

// TODO(v15): As of v15 mat.legacy-core no longer includes default typography styles.
//  The following line adds:
//    1. Default typography styles for all components
//    2. Styles for typography hierarchy classes (e.g. .mat-headline-1)
//  If you specify typography styles for the components you use elsewhere, you should delete this line.
//  If you don't need the default component typographies but still want the hierarchy styles,
//  you can delete this line and instead use:
//    `@include mat.legacy-typography-hierarchy(mat.define-legacy-typography-config());`
@include mat.all-legacy-component-typographies();
@include mat.legacy-core();

$cragcity-typography: mat.define-legacy-typography-config( 
    $font-family: 'Raleway',
    $display-4:     mat.define-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300, 'Helvetica', -0.05em),
    $display-3:     mat.define-typography-level(56px, 56px, 400, 'Helvetica', -0.02em),
    $display-2:     mat.define-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400, 'Helvetica', -0.005em),
    $display-1:     mat.define-typography-level(30px, 30px, 300, 'Helvetica', -0.02em),
    $headline:      mat.define-typography-level(24px, 32px, 400, 'Helvetica'),
    $title:         mat.define-typography-level(20px, 32px, 500, 'Helvetica'),
    $subheading-2:  mat.define-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400, 'Helvetica'),
    $subheading-1:  mat.define-typography-level(15px, 24px, 400, 'Helvetica'),
    $body-2:        mat.define-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500),
    $body-1:        mat.define-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400),
    $caption:       mat.define-typography-level(12px, 20px, 400),
    $button:        mat.define-typography-level(14px, 14px, 500),
    // Line-height must be unit-less fraction of the font-size.
    $input:         mat.define-typography-level(inherit, 1.125, 400)
);

$cragcity-blue: (
    50 : #e1eefd,
    100 : #b3d4fb,
    200 : #81b7f9,
    300 : #4e9af6,
    400 : #2884f4,
    500 : #026ef2,
    600 : #0266f0,
    700 : #015bee,
    800 : #0151ec,
    900 : #013fe8,
    A100 : #ffffff,
    A200 : #dce3ff,
    A400 : #a9bbff,
    A700 : #90a6ff,
    contrast: (
        50 : #000000,
        100 : #000000,
        200 : #000000,
        300 : #000000,
        400 : #ffffff,
        500 : #ffffff,
        600 : #ffffff,
        700 : #ffffff,
        800 : #ffffff,
        900 : #ffffff,
        A100 : #000000,
        A200 : #000000,
        A400 : #000000,
        A700 : #000000,
    )
);
$cragcity-primary: mat.define-palette($cragcity-blue, 500);
$cragcity-accent: mat.define-palette($cragcity-blue, 500, A100, A400);

$cragcity-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $cragcity-primary,
   accent: $cragcity-accent,
 )
));

@include mat.all-legacy-component-themes($cragcity-theme);
// TODO(v15): As of v15 mat.legacy-core no longer includes default typography styles.
//  The following line adds:
//    1. Default typography styles for all components
//    2. Styles for typography hierarchy classes (e.g. .mat-headline-1)
//  If you specify typography styles for the components you use elsewhere, you should delete this line.
//  If you don't need the default component typographies but still want the hierarchy styles,
//  you can delete this line and instead use:
//    `@include mat.legacy-typography-hierarchy($cragcity-typography);`
@include mat.all-legacy-component-typographies($cragcity-typography);
@include mat.legacy-core();


.mat-toolbar {
    $cragcity-toolbar-typography: mat.define-legacy-typography-configmat.define-legacy-typography-config( 
        $button: mat.define-typography-level(
            $font-family: Raleway,
            $font-weight: 400,
            $font-size: 14px
        )
    );

    $cragcity-toolbar-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
        typography: $cragcity-toolbar-typography
    ));

    @include mat.all-legacy-component-themes($cragcity-toolbar-theme);
}

@mixin cragcity_container {
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

@each $name, $value in $cragcity-palette {
    .bgcolor-#{$name} {
        background-color: $value !important;
    }
}

@each $name, $value in $cragcity-palette {
    .fntcolor-#{$name} {
        color: $value !important;
    }
}

@each $name, $value in $cragcity-palette {
    .bdrcolor-#{$name} {
        border-color: $value !important;
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to upgrade version one by one. So that you could rectify module/bundle dependencies accordingly with ease.

Also try this link https://update.angular.io/ for better guidance while upgrading angular version.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic. But I had a similar problem. It helped to add this:

```
 "build": {
      "options": {
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": ["node_modules"]
        }
      }
    }
```

in the **angular.json** file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).